# How to calculate the battery drain from a LED light knowing it uses 1.5 Ah/month?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

My knowledge of physics is basically zero, so I hope this question can be considered on-topic!

This [thingy](https://www.ctek.com/products/vehicle/indicator-panel-3-3m) connects to the battery of a vehicle (car, motorcycle, scooter etc) and shows the level of charge (green, amber, red) with a flashing led light.

**My question is: how to calculate the battery drain from using this led light? I.e. How much less would a battery last if connected to this thing?** Unfortunately it flashes all the time - it doesn't light up on demand (e.g. when you push a button).

The manufacturer states on its website that

> uses about 1.5mA. Than gives 1,5 Ah /month. An average self-discharge
>   for a battery is approx. 10 Ah/month.

What does this mean? How much less would a battery last if connected to this thing?
E.g. if we have a [7.4 Ah battery](https://www.carpimoto.it/en-GD/Bike_Yamaha_X-Max-300/Specific/Electrical-Components/Batteries/48784_GTZ8V-GS-Yuasa-Battery-GTZ8V.htm), does this mean that the led would drain the battery in less than 5 months (=7.4/1.5)? Whereas if the battery is 12.6Ah, like [this one](https://www.yuasa.co.uk/ytx14h-bs.html), then it would last 8.4 months?

EDIT: One reason for the confusion is that I read that lithium batteries are different, some say they are equivalent to standard batteries even if their (lithium's) Ah are lower

Of course:

- these calculations are theoretical - other factors which will affect
  the result will be what else is connected (eg alarm, tracker etc) and
  maybe the weather?
- this is more useful for small vehicles like small
  motorcycles than for cars and trucks, which tend to have larger
  batteries

PS The thingy is also useful because it provides an additional connection for a charger, which can be convenient if the battery is difficult to access (as is the case in some motorcycles and scooters) - you can install this in a storage compartment and then charge the battery by opening the compartment without taking apart panels etc.

Comment: Well, note the comment from the manufacturer - batteries self discharge, so your 7.4Ahr battery will die much sooner from that than your indicator.

Comment: Yes, I know, I did specify I appreciate the calculation is theoretical because there are other factors involved, but I'd like to understand how much more quickly this little led light will cause the battery to drain. Can you please help me understand if those calculations are correct? Similarly, if a battery self-discharges at 10Ah/month, does it mean a 10Ah battery will last one month before dying completely?

Comment: Well, the reality is far more complicated. For example, the voltage drops as the battery discharges. For lead-acid batteries, in most cases you can only get out about 1/2 the rated Amp-hours before the voltage is lower than "12V" appliances expect. Other types can generally get more out but the batteries are pricier.  Of course, nothing prevents you from adding a switch to only connect the thing when you want to.

Comment: Can you recommend any way to estimate what the additional battery drain would be? Eg say I have a 8Ah battery which lasts 1.5 months if I leave the vehicle unused. How much less would it last connecting this led light? Just a rough indicative estimation, to understand if battery life would be shortened by half or by a negligible amount. thanks!

Comment: Assume 4Ah to 'dead' in 1.5 months, so a 2.66 Ah parasitic drain. Your device adds 1.5, so call it 3.2 Ah, making 1.25 months to 'dead' rather than 1.5.